# How to add a class for forgot password link?

Tags: 6, navigation

I need to add a class for the forgot password link. How can I do using Drupal?

This is the actual link:

```
<a href="/user/password" title="">Have you forgotten your password?</a>
```

My expected link is this one:

```
<a href="/user/password" class="my_class" title="">Have you forgotten your password?</a>
```

How can I achieve this, without using jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_form_alter
 */
function login_register_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {    
  switch ($form_id) {
    case 'user_login':
       $form['#validate'][] = "login_register_validate";
    break;
  }
}
```

Just call the validate function:

```
/**
 * To add my_class in the forgot password link
 */
function login_register_validate($node, &$form) {
  // to add class in the forgot password link
  $_SESSION['messages']['error'][1] = 'Sorry, unrecognized username or password. <a class="my_class" href="/user/password" title="">Have you forgotten your password?</a>';
}
```

And it's done..

Here my fear is weather this is a right way ?

Expecting for comments..

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you create a custom block in "admin/structure/block/add," and then add that link with that class into the block? Place the block where you want to place it. It should still fulfill the same requirements.

Answer (score 1):

```
a[href="/user/password"] {
//css
//goes
//here
}
```

is another quick way of accomplishing something similar in most modern browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You can access it using a CSS selector such as the following one:

```
#user-login a {
}
```

You can use jQuery to add the class:

```
jQuery('#user-login a').addClass('my_class');
```